# Celery task hangs when .apply_async() or .delay() is used within request processed by Django, but works fine when invoked in shell

Tags: celery

Invokement of a following task:

```
task__determine_order_details_processing_or_created_status.apply_async(
    args=[order_record.Order_ID], 
    eta=datetime.now(GMT_timezone)+timedelta(minutes=1)
)
```

Ends up in the workers' timeout. It looks like the method is never releasing the worker to continue its job

```
web_1               | [2019-11-21 05:43:43 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:1559)
web_1               | [2019-11-21 05:43:43 +0000] [1559] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 1559)
web_1               | [2019-11-21 05:43:43 +0000] [1636] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1636
```

Whereas, the same command invoked with the usage of Django shell creates a completely working celerty task:

```
celery_1            | [2019-11-21 05:47:06,500: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: task__determine_order_details_processing_or_created_status[f94708be-a0ab-4853-8785-a11c8c7ca9f1]  ETA:[2019-11-21 05:48:06.304924+00:00]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
  web:
    build: ./server
    command: gunicorn server.wsgi:application --reload --limit-request-line 16376 --bind 0.0.0.0:8001 
    volumes:
      - ./server:/usr/src
    expose:
      - 8001
    env_file: .env.dev
    links:
      - memcached
    depends_on:
      - db_development_2
      - redis

  db_development_2:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
        - postgres_development3:/var/lib/postgresql/volume/
    env_file: .env.dev
    logging:
      driver: none

  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    restart: always
    logging:
      driver: none

celery:
    build: ./server
    command: celery -A server.celery worker -l info
    env_file: .env.dev
    volumes:
      - ./server:/usr/src
    depends_on:
      - db_development_2
      - redis
    restart: always

  celery-beat:
    build: ./server
    command: celery -A server.celery beat -l info
    env_file: .env.dev
    volumes:
      - ./server:/usr/src
    depends_on:
      - db_development_2
      - redis
    restart: always
    logging:
      driver: none
```

Answer (score -2):

Can you please share more details?

Error is from gunicorn right?

Are you running this in docker environment? Celery on different container?

What does WSGI<-->YOUR_APP command look like?

example:

```
gunicorn app.wsgi:tour_application -w 6 -b :8000 --timeout 120
```

Can you try with more time-out like 120 in above eg.?